# Can we directly get a refrence to UITextView's textview.text or do we need to make a copy of it to use it as a NSString from objC?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Can we directly get a refrence textview.text and use it as a objC's NSString .If yes ,do we need to handle memory dellocation or is it taken care by ARC?

If we cann't directly take a refrence ,do we have another option than making a copy of textview.text and use it as a ObjC's NSString?

I want to use UITextView.text string in objectiveC whenever character changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` property of `UITextView` is has already has `copy` as it's attribute - [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618623-text?language=objc); which means whenever you try to access `textView.text` into your local `NSString` property/variable, a copy of `text` will be created and stored.

You will have it's ownership and depending on the scope of the your property, ARC will decide to release it.